# Unit Testing a JS script with Jest: Can I mock an ES6 class

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs, es6-class

when I import a class from a module

```
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
```

How can I mock it ?

```
jest.mock("google-auth-library");  // not mocking directly OAuth2Client

jest.mock("google-auth-library", OAuth2Client ) // is incorrect
```

And if I add the online implementation, I don't have the class name

```
jest.mock("google-auth-library", () => {
   return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        setCredentials: setCredentialsMock,
        getAccessToken: getAccessTokenMock
      }
   })
});
```

so I cannot call the constructor :

```
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client({...});
```

Feedback welcome

**UPDATE 1 --**

Here as the most important coding from google-auth-library-nodejs related  to my issue

**google-auth-library-nodejs module**

**=======================================
/src/auth/index.ts**
        ...
        export {.., OAuth2Client,...} from './auth/oauth2client';
        ...
        const auth = new GoogleAuth();
        export {auth, GoogleAuth};

```
    =======================================
    /src/auth/oauth2client.js

    import {AuthClient} from './authclient';
    ...
    export class OAuth2Client extends AuthClient {
      ....
      constructor(clientId?: string, clientSecret?: string, redirectUri?: string);
      constructor(
         ...
        super();
        ...
        this._clientId = opts.clientId;
        this._clientSecret = opts.clientSecret;
        this.redirectUri = opts.redirectUri;
        ...
      }
      ...
      getAccessToken(): Promise<GetAccessTokenResponse>;
      ...
    }
```

**=======================================
/src/auth/authclient.ts**

```
    import {Credentials} from './credentials';
    ...
    export abstract class AuthClient extends EventEmitter {
       ...
      setCredentials(credentials: Credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
      }
    }
```

**=======================================
/src/auth/credentials.js**

```
    export interface Credentials {
      refresh_token?: string|null;
      expiry_date?: number|null;
      access_token?: string|null;
      token_type?: string|null;
      id_token?: string|null;
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED ...  using the following specs :

```
jest.mock("google-auth-library");
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');

const setCredentialsMock = jest.fn();
const getAccessTokenMock = jest.fn();

OAuth2Client.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    setCredentials: setCredentialsMock,
    getAccessToken: getAccessTokenMock
  }
});

import index from "../index.js"

describe('testing...', () => { 
  it("should setCredentials correctly....", () => {
    // GIVEN
    const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client("clientId", "clientSecret", "redirectUri");
    // WHEN
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: "aRefreshToken"});
    // THEN
    expect(setCredentialsMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ refresh_token: "aRefreshToken" });
  });
});
```

Comment: Trying to get it to work with typescript and mocked return / reject values. [This](https://dev.to/jackcaldwell/mocking-es6-class-methods-with-jest-bd7) helped...
```
import { OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library";
const mockedVerifyIdToken = jest.fn();

it("returns 404 on garbage token", async () => {
  OAuth2Client.prototype.verifyIdToken = mockedVerifyIdToken;
  mockedVerifyIdToken.mockRejectedValueOnce(
    Error("Wrong number of segments in token")
  );
  const res = await request(app).get("/api/auth/google?code=12345679");
  expect(res.status).toBe(404);
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me.

This worked for me.

```
jest.mock('google-auth-library', () => {

return {
    OAuth2Client: jest.fn(() => ({
        verifyIdToken: jest.fn((variable) => Promise.resolve({

            getPayload: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({

                email: 'test@test.com'

            })

        }))

    }))
};
```

});